# SSRS Subscription: Error Saving To File Share

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am attempting to run a Timed Subscription in SSRS 2008 and have the results save out to a file share. The subscription runs great when I have it email it's results but fails with this error when I try to save to a file share:

*Failure writing file \ServerName\ShareName\Test.csv : Could not find file '\ServerName\ShareName\Test.csv'.*

So Far, this is what I have unsuccessfully tried/confirmed

1. The subscription runs under my NT context and I've confirmed I have rights to create files in the share
2. I didn't expect it to matter but I created an empty text file name test.csv in the share. This made no difference
3. There are quite a few references online regarding write failures but non relate to "Could not find file".
4. I am the owner of the subject and the report
5. Emailing the report works fine
6. I tried leaving the file name blank in the subscription so SSRS would create the file name based on the RDL name (idea based on comments in BOL) but this is now a required field.

This is extremely frustrating. Has anyone had problems with this before? This seems like a slam dunk simple thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Are you qualifying your server name with a double backslash?

e.g.

\\ServerName

Not

\ServerName

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the "Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source" box checked in Properties/Data Sources for that specific report?

Comment: I did not but tried changing it without success. I've pulled the logs from the database but am having issues getting the text logs off of the server because of permissions issues.